# Updating image clip with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on the code below. Why am I not able to change the image clip value by the range slider?

```js
$('#myRange').on('input', function() {

  var nn = $(this).val();
  $("img").css({
    'clip': 'rect(0% ' + nn + '%, 0%, 0%)',
    '-webkit-clip-path': 'inset(0% ' + nn + '%, 0%, 0%)',
    'clip-path': 'inset(0% ' + nn + '%, 0%, 0%)'
  });

});
```

```css
img {
  clip: rect(0% 50% 0% 0%);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0% 50% 0% 0%);
  clip-path: inset(0% 50% 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
<img src="https://img.fcbayern.com/image/fetch/f_auto,h_371,q_auto:good,w_660/https://fcbayern.com/binaries/content/gallery/fc-bayern/homepage/saison-19-20/frauen/news/fcb-frauen-mannschaftsbild_getty_270719.jpg/fcb-frauen-mannschaftsbild_getty_270719.jpg/fcbhippo%3Axtralargesixteentonine%3Fv%3D1564992156070"
  class="img-fluid">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `spaces`

```js
$('#myRange').on('input', function() {

  var nn = $(this).val();
  $("img").css({
    'clip': 'rect(0% ' + nn + '% 0% 0%)',
    '-webkit-clip-path': 'inset(0% ' + nn + '% 0% 0%)',
    'clip-path': 'inset(0% ' + nn + '% 0% 0%)'
  });

});
```

```css
img {
  clip: rect(0% 50% 0% 0%);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0% 50% 0% 0%);
  clip-path: inset(0% 50% 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
<img src="https://img.fcbayern.com/image/fetch/f_auto,h_371,q_auto:good,w_660/https://fcbayern.com/binaries/content/gallery/fc-bayern/homepage/saison-19-20/frauen/news/fcb-frauen-mannschaftsbild_getty_270719.jpg/fcb-frauen-mannschaftsbild_getty_270719.jpg/fcbhippo%3Axtralargesixteentonine%3Fv%3D1564992156070"
  class="img-fluid">
```

The effective way of using [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

```js
$('#myRange').on('input', function() {
  var nn = $(this).val();
  $('img').css('--clip-right', nn + '%');
});
```

```css
img {
  --clip-right: 50%;
  clip: rect(0% var(--clip-right) 0% 0%);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0% var(--clip-right) 0% 0%);
  clip-path: inset(0% var(--clip-right) 0% 0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
</div>
<img src="https://img.fcbayern.com/image/fetch/f_auto,h_371,q_auto:good,w_660/https://fcbayern.com/binaries/content/gallery/fc-bayern/homepage/saison-19-20/frauen/news/fcb-frauen-mannschaftsbild_getty_270719.jpg/fcb-frauen-mannschaftsbild_getty_270719.jpg/fcbhippo%3Axtralargesixteentonine%3Fv%3D1564992156070"
  class="img-fluid">
```